# postgres - change one column to the same value by name

Tags: postgresql

for example i have column that look like this:

```
name | id | value 
A      1     aa 
A      2     ab 
B      3     bc 
C      4     ca 
C      5     cb
```

Is there any way to change it to this ?

```
name | id | value 
A      1     aa 
A      1     ab 
B      3     bc 
C      4     ca 
C      4     cb
```

Comment: Do you want to _permanently_ change those values (i.e. run an `update` statement) or do you just want to _display_ the values like that (i.e. in a `select` statement)

Comment: Permanently @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) that numbers the rows, and use that select statement to supply the values for the update:

```
update the_table
  set id = t.rn
from (
  select name, 
         id, 
         dense_rank() over (order by name)  as rn
  from the_table
) t
where (t.name, t.id) = (the_table.name, the_table.id);
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0e987/1

This assumes that the existing combination `(id, name)` is unique. If that is not the case, you would need to use the [`ctid`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-system-columns.html) column to match the rows between the inner select and the table itself:

```
update the_table
  set id = t.rn
from (
  select name, 
         id, 
         ctid,
         dense_rank() over (order by name)  as rn
  from the_table
) t
where t.ctid = the_table.ctid;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i have one more question. If i don't have the name column, but only `(id, values)` and i want to do the same, i need to use ctid, right ?

Comment: @BilboBagosz: yes, if you don't have a unique identifier for a row, then you have to use `ctid`. This is one of the rare situations where it _can_ safely be used as a key.

Comment: one more thing. If i have id with larger numbers for example: `(1275868, 1275958, 1275910)` how i can resolve the same problem? Is there any function like to dense_rank which can handle with that ?

Comment: @BilboBagosz: what exactly do you mean with "can handle that"? What is the problem you have?

Comment: dense_rank is good when i want to order id from 1. But if i have id which are not numbered from 1, but have different values. For example:

    `A | 152 | ca
    A | 173 | cb
    B | 163 | ba
    C | 285 | bb`
    C | 273 | be

And i want to look like this:

    `A | 152 | ca
    A | 152 | cb
    B | 163 | ba
    C | 285 | bb
    C | 285 | be`

Comment: Then why didn't you include this information in the question? It's not very helpful if you change the circumstances _after_ you got an answer. But as long as the values can be ordered properly, `dense_rank()` will work just fine. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: i know, sorry for that. I have table like this: `A | 1290372 | cc
 B | 1286532 | cb B | 1293600 | ca` and when i trying your function i get this `A | 1    | 1286339B | 2    | 1286471
 C | 2    | 1286471`